# Which version of FFTW

Tags: libraries, mpi, fftw

At the moment, I'm installing the "[GADGET-2](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/)" application. In its documentation it says "Note that the MPI-capable version 2.x of FFTW is required, the new version 3 lacks MPI capability at this point. [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) is only needed for simulations that use the TreePM algorithm."

Is this still true for the current version 3.3.3? Should I use 2.1.5 or 3.3.3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFTW3 now supports MPI, but the APIs between 2 and 3 have many differences. Thus, I'm 99% certain you should use FFTW2. However, if you ask around, you may be able to find a usable version of Gadget-3 which has been slated for but not yet officially released for awhile now. We see a lot of both on our systems.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try with FFTW 2.1.5 and if this does not work, I will go vor GADGET-3